# UIKeyboard Disabling Touch Events

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

When the keyboard is displayed in my app, no touches will work in my view. I will tap a `UITextField` and the keyboard will be presented. Now that it is displayed, I cannot tap on other textfields,buttons or select text even in the active textfield.

Any ideas what may cause this

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have found that because I animate the view upwards a little when the keyboard is displayed this is causing a problem. I have the master, view controller view. Inside this is `formContainerView` which contains my two `UITextField`s and `UIButton`.

I animate `formContainerView` up so that my fields aren't hidden behind the keyboard. I run the following code to do this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:animationOptionsWithCurve(curve) animations:^{

        [self.formContainerView setFrame:CGRectOffset(self.formContainerView.frame, 0, -220.0f)];
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {  }];
```

So I just offset the view by 220 pixels. If I set this to 0, i.e. don't animate the position, all touches work. But by moving the view up, all touches fail to work.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    if ([txtfld_firstname isFirstResponder])
    {
        [txtfld_firstname resignFirstResponder]; 
        [txtfld_secondname becomeFirstResponder];    
    }
     return YES;
}
```

first set to the delegate for the textfield.
and after that write the above method when you click on the first textfield and after that press return button on the keyboard this (textfield delegate)method call and your keyboard disable.

Comment: Daxesh, thank you but this isn't really a good solution. While it allows me to navigate through textfields and dismiss the keyboard via the return key, it doesn't let the user tap on the text fields or allow use of the text selection tools, such as copy and paste.